# Setting to submit data from HTML of textarea in view.py in Django and set as temporary data

Tags: python, django

Background of the project: I am working on a text-to-speech (TTS) converter with Django. I have the python code that works well for the TTS converting and output the audio file, but I want to make it as a web app and gonna deploy to the cloud, that's why I am plugging it to Django.

There are only two variables that input from the user: the text content that would be converted and selected language. My thought is to set the input variables as temporary items so that it wouldn't bomb the server - so to the output file to save as temporary file and automatically download to the user and delete the file after finish downloading.

After searching for possible similar cases and solution, I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866307/python-and-django-how-to-use-in-memory-and-temporary-files) which is explaining how to use in memory and temporary files, but it seems only for uploading files.

My question is, right now I am coding to send the data to the sqlite3 database but obviously it doesn't make sense to input data and then delete frequently. I am thinking to use session with the view.py as follow (not sure if it works):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text_to_be_converted = request.session['text_content']
        if not text_to_be_converted:
            return render(request, 'index.html')
        language = request.session['language']
```

But I have no idea how to modify the HTML part, especially the setting of form action - what should I set for the form action?

Here's the HTML part:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Text-to-Speech Converter｜文字-語音轉換器</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
      {% load static %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <form action="/converter/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2> Text-to-Speech Converter<br>文字-語音轉換器</h2>

            <fieldset>
              <label for="text-label-text-content">Text Content｜文字內容：</label>
              <textarea id="text_content" name="text_content"></textarea>

              <label for="language_select">Language｜語言：</label>
              <select id="language" name="language">
                <optgroup label="Select Language｜選擇語言">
                  <option value="cantonese">Cantonese｜廣東話</option>
                  <option value="mandarin">Mandarin｜國語</option>
                  <option value="putonghua">Putonghua｜普通話</option>
                  <option value="english">English｜英文</option>
                  <option value="french">French｜法文</option>
                  <option value="japanese">Japanese｜日文</option>
                  <option value="vietnamese">Vietnamese｜越南文</option>
                </optgroup>
              </select>
            </fieldset>

            <p>Click "Transform｜轉換" to transform and download the audio.</p>
            <p>按「Transform｜轉換」轉換並下載語音檔。</p>

            <center><button type="submit">Transform｜轉換</button></center>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think my urls.py setting is fine but just in case I leave them here.

This is the project/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('converter/', include('converter.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

And this is the converter/urls.py (app):

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After delete the whole thing and redo it step by step with testing, I think I kinda figure out. The explanation is attached at each line.
The code is as following:

```
def index(request):
    text_content = request.POST.get('text_content') # use the POST method to get the text content
    language = request.POST.get('language') # use the POST method to get the language value
    request.session['current_content'] = text_content # store the content to session
    request.session['current_language'] = language # store the language value to session
    print(request.POST.get)  # print the line to get the POST content.
    print(request.POST.get('text_content'))  # test if getting the text_content through POST method, specifically
    print(request.POST.get('language'))  # test if getting the language through POST method
    print("the content in session is: " + str(request.session.get('current_content')))  # test if get the content to the session, to test if the variable of the POST.get works well
    if text_content:
        print("it works.")  # simply a line to test if this "if" loop works well
        print("the text content is " + text_content + ", and the language is " + language + ".") # testing if the session works well
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

In this case, the content should be save in django.session. I am not sure if this code above is correct but from the testing it runs well.