# How to add files in Django session?

Tags: django, django-sessions

I want to get some files from the user and after getting the files, I want the user should make a payment after payment is done, an order should be created and the files should be stored against that order in the Database. I know how to create an order and store the files in a database.

I have used Django's sessions to store the string data. But want to store files also. I have used the following code :

In HTML:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <input type="file" name="filename">

</form>
```

In views.py :

```
if request.method == "POST":
    request.session['filename'] = request.FILES['filename']
```

It throws errors as :
**Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error been thrown because **you're not allowed to put non-serializable objects into the session**.

You may encounter this problem by saving it on the server and just save in the session the file name for future usage.

**See more:**

[Python and Django - How to use in memory and temporary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866307/python-and-django-how-to-use-in-memory-and-temporary-files)